# Splunk as syslog analyzer

Tags: logging

I have running centralized syslog server (rsyslog on CentOS6, which works perfect). Next step it was to add Splunk as a syslog analyzing tool. All was installed perfectly - Splunk works, can log in to the front end and add data source (TCP port 514) but from there I don't see any data indexed by Splunk.

rysylog config for data storage and processing looks like:

```
$ModLoad ommysql
$ModLoad ommysql
*.* :ommysql:127.0.0.1,rsysdb,rsyslog,password
*.* @@localhost
```

Any clue why Splunk is not receiving any data?

Thanks

Comment: It is very difficult to predict what is wrong with your setup. Most probably you did not configure the data source properly.

Comment: While Splunk can often be used in the place of a SIEM or for security operations it is not necessarily a security tool. You may find more expertise in this tool at our sister site for Information Technology Professionals [SF].

Comment: @ScottPack thanks for pointing me to the proper site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, got issue resolved by using local IP instead a domain 'localhost' so line for syslog forwarding to Splunk (TCP connection) looks like

`*.* @@127.0.0.1`

as is on the same server as rsyslog. Splunk is set to listen to TCP port 514 data set as syslog.